# Can a YAML anchor be defined elsewhere than its first usage?

Tags: yaml, yaml-anchors

I'm writing a fairly complex YAML document (such as for several Bitbucket Pipelines) and I have a section that is repeated in multiple places. I'd like to use a YAML anchor for modularity, that is, to ensure the section can be easily maintained (without drift or unintended discrepancies between these multiple places).

Does my `&`anchor *have* to be defined inline in the first place where the repeated node occurs? Or is it possible to just have a `*`reference in that location, and to instead define the anchor somewhere separate (i.e., either at the very top or bottom of the YAML file, preferably somehow *outside* of the node tree for the document, like as for a subroutine called from multiple places inside a main function)? I think this would be more readable in my case, because there would be more obvious symmetry between the lines of config that share the repetition (rather than making the initial instance look completely different from the subsequent instances).